# How to set myapp.herokuapp.com mx record to point to mx.sendgrid.net?

Tags: email, dns, sendgrid

I am trying to get my mail exchanger record to point to sendgrid, but I cannot seem to find the option on heroku.  Does anyone know where this setting is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, *as far as I can tell*, Heroku does not allow you to set `MX` records for their subdomains.

To counteract this, you can do one of two things. You may setup MX records for some domain (or subdomain) *you* own, and point that to SendGrid. *OR* you may use the preconfigured [bymail.in](http://bymail.in). This service has `MX` records preconfigured to send to SendGrid. To use it simply direct your users to email `your-sendgrid-or-heroku-username.bymail.in` (e.g. `yay@nquinlan.bymail.in`).